# How to loop while() on a form application

Tags: while-loop, c++-cli

I want to create a loop in my `windowform` application in C++/CLI.

I have the following button:

```
private: System::Void button17_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  this->button17->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Lime;

  while (true) {
    if (button17->Enabled == true) {
      HWND hwnd1;
      hwnd1 = FindWindow(NULL, "1");
    }
    else {
      break;
    }

  } /// End while
}
```

I created a button with a `while()` statement. When I press the 'on' button, the loop should execute, and when I press this button again, the loop should end, and the program should stop this while statement.

However, when I press my button, the program does what I want, but my application suspends and can't do anything. What am I doing wrong, and how can make a loop when I press a button, and stop the loop when I press the button again?

Answer (score -1):

C++/CLI is not "just C++". It is for writing code to interface C# or other .Net languages to C++ code. If you want to write "just C++", make a C++ project and use MFC for the GUI.

In any language, the answer is this: A while loop in a button handler will cause the UI thread to be busy with the while loop, and not with such things as redrawing the UI or responding to the subsequent button push. For this, I'd start a background thread at program load, and use a synchronization object to trigger whether the thread is doing work or not.

Answer (score -1):

You are blocking your current thread.

You need to take this loop and put it in a thread. Then launch the thread to run in the background.

```
while (true) {
if (button17->Enabled == true) {
  HWND hwnd1;
  hwnd1 = FindWindow(NULL, "1");
}
else {
  break;
} 
} /// End while
```